# Showing Error : superclass mismatch for class DatePickerInput (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, formtastic

Platform: Fedora 16

Rails 3

Formtastic 2

Im trying to install https://github.com/kristianmandrup/formtastic_datepicker-rails3x

After in including the Gem in Gemfile as

```
gem 'formtastic_datepicker-rails3x', :git => 'git://github.com/kristianmandrup/formtastic_datepicker-rails3x.git'
```

I tried scaffolding as

```
rails g scaffold due_date date:date
```

I got error

```
/home/sreekeshos/.bundler/ruby/1.8/formtastic_datepicker-rails3x-d66ab9db54bd/lib/formtastic/date_picker_input.rb:2: superclass mismatch for class DatePickerInput (TypeError)
    from /home/sreekeshos/.bundler/ruby/1.8/formtastic_datepicker-rails3x-d66ab9db54bd/lib/formtastic_datepicker-rails3x.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/sreekeshos/.bundler/ruby/1.8/formtastic_datepicker-rails3x-d66ab9db54bd/lib/formtastic_datepicker-rails3x.rb:2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/sreekeshos/Ruby Example/Form sample/form_sample/config/application.rb:7
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:24:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:24
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6
```

I've searched other related questions, but they all involved migrating from Ruby 2 to 3 or erb vs eruby.